# Android camera preview SurfaceTexture translation boundaries

Tags: android, opengl-es, android-camera, opengl-es-2.0

I'm working on a project that requires me to 'pan' around the camera preview to find a small area.  I've got this partially working by rendering the preview to a SurfaceTexture and applying transforms to the vertices passed into the vertex shader.  The 'cropped' area that the user sees and is able to 'pan' around in is 1024x1024 and the camera preview size is 1920x1080.

The problem I'm having is essentially finding the bounds of the preview.  I can translate the vertices entirely off the screen and it will just continue to move.  I've tried several strategies to solve this problem, but I've not had any luck.

The first thing I tried was to calculate the value in the shape vertices that would make the preview flush with the view.  without any scale applied, the range of the shape vertices should be [-1,1].  This is true with the vertices below for the up, down and left direction.  However, I found through trial and error that the right edge has an offset of .12.  This is completely logical because the camera preview is much wider than the view that is showing it.  I'm not sure how I'm supposed to account for that in order to enforce a boundary.

```
/* Initial position of the shape */
{ -1.0  1.0 
  -1.0 -1.0 
   1.0 -1.0 
   1.0  1.0 }

/* Right edge against the screen */
{    -1.12  1.0 
     -1.12 -1.0 
      0.88 -1.0 
      0.88  1.0  }
```

Out of curiosity, the next thing I tried was using glReadPixel to get the column of pixels at the edge of the screen.  I found that the pixels I got were all equal if the shape was translated off the screen.  This all worked up until I hit the offset mentioned above. The pixels I had were all equal after [-1,1] effectively cutting off the last part.  This was just something I was using to test the waters.

```
glReadPixel(1023, 0, 1, 1024);
```

Given that I'm using openGL es 2.0, it's obviously hard to interpret data from the shaders.  To try to see what was going on, I wrote a small utility function to apply the transformations in the shader and print them out and that is where the above vertices came from.

Does anyone have any insight on this?  I've tried to search for anything that would point me in the right direction but I'm coming up with nothing.  If there is any code that would be helpful please let me know and I will post it if I can.

```
public void printFinalShapeCoords(float coords[]) {
    float shapeCoords[] = new float[8];
    for(int i = 0; i < coords.length; i+=2) {
        mScratchVector[0] = coords[i];
        mScratchVector[1] = coords[i+1];
        mScratchVector[2] = 0;
        mScratchVector[3] = 1;
        Matrix.multiplyMV(mTempVector, 0, mMVPMatrix, 0, mScratchVector, 0);
        shapeCoords[i] = mTempVector[0];
        shapeCoords[i+1] = mTempVector[1];
    }
    Log.e(TAG, "Final shape coords:\n"+Arrays.toString(shapeCoords));
}
```

Vertex Shader:

```
                "uniform mat4 u_MVPMatrix;"+                /* 4x4 MVP matrix */
            "attribute vec4 vPosition;" +               /* Position vector */
            "attribute vec2 inputTextureCoordinate;" +  /* Texture coordinates */
            "varying vec2 textureCoordinate;" +         /* Texture coordinates that are passed to the fragment shader */
            "void main()" +
            "{"+
                "gl_Position = u_MVPMatrix*vPosition;"+ /* Multiply the MVP matrix and the position vector */
                "textureCoordinate = inputTextureCoordinate;" +
            "}";
```

Fragment Shader:

```
            "#extension GL_OES_EGL_image_external : require\n"+
            "precision mediump float;" +
            "varying vec2 textureCoordinate;\n" +
            "uniform samplerExternalOES s_texture;\n" +
            "void main() {" +
            "  gl_FragColor = texture2D( s_texture, textureCoordinate );\n" +
            "}";
```

EDIT (10/24/2014 3:07 PM EST)

A comment mentioned that it wasn't quite clear what I'm trying to accomplish and I would like to try to clarify a bit.

Essentially, I'm trying to show a portion of the camera preview while being able to view the remaining preview when a button is pressed.  The portion that is being shown is 1024x1024 while the camera preview size is 1920x1080.  An example of the behavior I'm going for is in the Gallery app.  When looking at a picture, the user can 'zoom' and then 'traverse' the rest of the picture.  I am trying to do this but with the camera preview instead of a static image.  As I mentioned before, I have the zooming/panning working correctly, but I can't find the point at which to stop panning.

Comment: Is your MVP matrix the one you got from [getTransformMatrix](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/SurfaceTexture.html#getTransformMatrix(float[]))?

Comment: @mikkokoo No, it isn't.  I'm using getTransformMatrix on the texture vertices on each draw call.  The matrix I get from that function is almost an identity matrix but instead of a positive 1 for the y it's a negative 1 which flips the camera preview to the correct orientation.  The MVP matrix holds the other transformations that are applied to the shape vertices.

Comment: Ok. If you are just trying to blit the texture to the view (i.e no 3D transformation) you could skip the matrix and use [clip space](http://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_transform.html) coordinates directly for vertex position. Then move the texture coordinates to pan the image. I don't think I quite get what you are trying to do though.

Comment: @mikkokoo I edited the question to try and clarify a bit.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that you have to keep track of your offset and scale manually (i.e. force the offset to be within certain boundaries after the user has panned).

The way I do it is to use [clip space](http://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_transform.html) coordinates directly. So with 1024x1024 view and 1920x1080 texture just have your vertices be for y [-1,1] and for x [-1.77778,1.77778] (then the scale [1.0,1.0,1.0] floods the view).

Remove the MVP from your shader altogether.

Then introduce uniforms scale and offset. Panning moves the offset, zooming changes the scale.

Thus:

```
attribute mediump vec3 vertex;
attribute mediump vec2 texCoord;
varying mediump vec2 v_texCoord;
uniform mediump vec3 offset;
uniform mediump vec3 scale;
void main(){
 gl_Position=vec4((vertex-offset)*scale,1.0);
 v_texCoord=vec2(texCoord);
}
```

In Java have a sanity check function that makes sure offset is always within the vertex boundaries, remember to take scale into consideration.

Comment: This looks promising; I should be able to try this today and get back to you.  Thank You

Comment: Sorry for the delay.  I removed the matrix from the shader and added the offset/scale uniforms which has the same effect as I had with the MVP matrix.  Now that I have that, I'm not sure I understand what you mean by 'have your vertices be y [-1,1]...'.  I realize what those ranges are, but I'm not sure how to 'enforce' those ranges.  It seems that the view is 'centered' in that it is an equal distance to all of the sides except the right side.  Do I need to calculate the distance from the edge of view to the edge of the texture?

Comment: It just means that your vertices should be `[-1.77778,1],[-1.77778,-1],[1.77778,-1],[1.77778,1]`. I.e. they remain the same, then with offset and scale you control what is shown. All texture coordinates should be one or zero for the vertices.

Comment: Would I need to use a projecting matrix to do that or just set the initial shape vertices to the values you listed above?  I tried setting them to the initial shape vertices and it threw off the aspect ratio.  I'm not trying to be dense, I'm just unsure of how exactly to do what you're suggesting.